# Can I change a element state in react without changing every element state?

Tags: reactjs, state

im making a portfolio website and have multiple different buttons with skills which contain an img and p tag. I want to show the description of each tag everytime a user clicks on the button. how can I do this? right now everytime user clicks it, all buttons show description.

const Skills = () => {
const [state, setState] = useState(false)

```
let skills = [
    { id: 1, desc: 'HTML5', state: false, img: htmlIcon },
    { id: 2, desc: 'CSS3', state: false, img: cssIcon },
    { etc....}

const showDesc = (id) => {
    console.log(skills[id-1] = !state);
    setState(!state)
    }
return (
{skills.map(skill => (
    <button onClick={(id) => showDesc(skill.id)}>
        <img style={ state ? {display:'none'} : {display:'block'}} src={skill.img} />
        <p style={ state ? {display:'block'} : {display:'none'}}>{skill.desc}</p>
    </button>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to manipulate element state instead of entry list. But if you really need to manipulate entry list you should add that list to your state. Then when you want to show/hide specific item, you need to find that item in state and correctly update entry list by making a copy of that list (with updated item). For example you can do it like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Skills = () => {
  const [skills, setSkills] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      desc: 'HTML5',
      state: false,
      img: htmlIcon, // your icon
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      desc: 'CSS3',
      state: false,
      img: cssIcon, // your icon
    },
  ]);

  const showDesc = (id) => {
    const newSkills = skills.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return {
          ...item,
          state: !item.state,
        };
      }

      return item;
    });

    setSkills(newSkills);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {skills.map(({
        id,
        img,
        state,
        desc,
      }) => (
        <button type="button" key={id} onClick={() => showDesc(id)}>
          <img alt="img" style={state ? { display: 'none' } : { display: 'block' }} src={img} />
          <p style={state ? { display: 'block' } : { display: 'none' }}>{desc}</p>
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Instead of manipulating all list, you can try to move show/hide visibility to list item itself. Create separate component for item and separate component for rendering that items. It will help you to simplify logic and make individual component responsible for it visibility.

> About list rendering you can read more [here](https://medium.com/swlh/react-tips-rendering-lists-dynamic-components-and-default-props-77fe091c34c6)

For example you can try something like this as alternative:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const skills = [
  {
    id: 1,
    desc: 'HTML5',
    img: htmlIcon, // your icon 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    desc: 'CSS3',
    img: cssIcon, // your icon
  },
];

const SkillItem = ({
  img,
  desc = '',
}) => {
  const [visibility, setVisibility] = useState(false);

  const toggleVisibility = () => {
    setVisibility(!visibility);
  };

  const content = visibility
    ? <p>{desc}</p>
    : <img alt="img" src={img} />;

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onClick={toggleVisibility}>
        {content}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const SkillList = () => skills.map(({
  id,
  img,
  desc,
}) => <SkillItem img={img} desc={desc} key={id} />);
```